# Linear programming example need help

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

***I'm new here I have one example of linear programming so if you can point me in the right direction.
Here is the text of exercise:

**The company manufactures two-unit home air conditioners, which have a capacity of 350 units
per month. The production cost of the air conditioner in Drive 1 is 30,000 dinars, and in Drive 2 it is
27.000 din. The price of the stored devices is 2,800 dinars for each started month. Assessment
demand for the next three months is 400, 500 and 600 devices.
Determined the optimal number of devices that should produce each drive in the next three
months, with at least 50 devices being manufactured in each facility.**

**Can anyone help me to transfer this in python code or excel**

[Updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acL2b.png) **Updated version please have a look**

(max) x1+x2

x1 - capacity in D1

(D - Drive1,Drive2)

x2 - capacity in D2

---

constraints:

50 <= x1 <= 350

50 <= x2 <= 350

x1,x2 >= 50

x1,x2 <= 350

---

expenses: 2800

---

27200 * x1 = P1 (P1 profit)

24200 * x2 = P2 (P2 profit)

M1= x1+x2 = 400

M2 = x1+x2 = 500  (M - month)

M3 = x1+x2 = 600

27200 * x1 + 24200 * x2

**Guys I'm on the good track?**

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you having trouble with formulating the problem as a linear program, or actually solving the linear program?

Comment: I have problem to formulate the problem and how to start. Sorry for a bad explanation I'm new to this. Thanks

Comment: Have you done similar problems before? You need to determine your decision variables, define a cost function, and derive constraints from the given information.

Comment: No, I'm totally new to this I made some sketches in my workbook but my head is all over the place. Is this too hard the first assignment for a beginner.

Comment: @Math1000 hey sorry to bother you, can you please take a look at my progress? Thanks in advance.